# How can I convert f(x,y) to a 2-D matrix (i.e. lookup table)?

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, octave, lookup-tables

Given `f = @(x,y) [something with a scalar result]`, what's the best way that I can compute a lookup matrix `A` such that `A(x,y) == f(x,y)` for any `x,y` within a particular range and domain?

Let's say a function called `lookupTable(f,range,domain)` did what I want. Then `lookupTable(@(x,y) x * y, 12, 12)` would yield a matrix containing the multiplication table from `1*1=1` to `12*12=144`.

Or let's say I want a 6x6 matrix with all zeros except for a one in row 3, column 5. Instead of literally writing in that matrix, or creating an all-zero matrix and then modifying it, I could write `lookupTable(@(x,y) x==3&&y==5, 6, 6)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a combination of [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate 2-D input grids for `x` and `y` and [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) to evaluate the scalar function `f` at each grid pair. For your first example, you can do this:

```
[y, x] = meshgrid(1:12, 1:12);  %# Or just [y, x] = meshgrid(1:12);
lutable = arrayfun(f, x, y);
```

Note that I reversed the order of the inputs and outputs to MESHGRID so that values of `x` increased going down the rows of the resulting lookup table.

Comment: perfect. this is exactly what i was looking for. nevermind that i actually figured this out and used this approach before seeing your answer :)

Comment: @gnovice: the reversal of x and y is why I normally use `ndgrid` rather than `meshgrid`

Comment: @Jonas: Good point. NDGRID would probably make things clearer in this case. I just have a habit of turning to MESHGRID first for any grid creation.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
function a = lookupTable(func, cols, rows)
    a = zeros(cols, rows);
    for i = 1:cols
        for j=1:rows
            a(i,j) = func(i, j);
        end 
    end
end
```

called with

```
lookupTable(@(x,y) x==3&&y==5, 6, 6)
```

Comment: i was looking for a native/vectorized way to do this with no side effecting assignments, but maybe there's no such thing.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with anonymous functions, at lease I know no other way.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a function to do that, you can use it.

It works for any number of inputs.

```
function varargout = ndfun( fun, varargin )
%%% [A B]=ndfun(@foo,X,Y)
%%% ---> [A(i,j) B(i,j)]=foo(X(i),Y(j))
% Example:
% ndfun(@times,[1 2 3],[ 6 7 8 9])
% ans =
%      6     7     8     9
%     12    14    16    18
%     18    21    24    27
%%% par Oli 03/2012

args=cell(1,nargin-1);
[args{:}]=ndgrid(varargin{:});

varargout=cell(1,max(1,nargout));

[varargout{:}]=arrayfun(fun,args{:});

end
```